# Is 'uses' directive in Delphi's unit makes application bigger or slower?

Tags: delphi

I want to know from people who are smarter than me about Delphi, if there's a lot of unit imports in 'uses' directive, is it making my application slower or bigger?

Or if there's a lot of units that I import but not using, is it better to remove them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, using units that you don't need to will result in larger executables.  Usually it makes little difference to performance of the code.

Tools like [Gexperts](http://www.gexperts.org/) and [CnPack](http://www.cnpack.org/index.php?lang=en) have wizards to automatically remove unused units.

The main thing you can do to reduce executable size is to [disable RTTI](http://www.zipplet.co.uk/index.php/content/articles_programming_delphi2010rtti).

EDIT: In older versions of Delphi, the linker removes unused methods from the executable. Even then, code in the initialization/finalization sections of unused methods can result in extra code being linked into the executable and thus increasing its size.

Delphi 2010 introduced a new improved version of RTTI. One of the side effects of this is that unused functions are no longer removed by the linker.  This behaviour can be [customised to some degree](http://www.zipplet.co.uk/index.php/content/articles_programming_delphi2010rtti).

Comment: This answer is in general wrong in an important way. While using units you don't need will slow down the IDE's code-insight feature, and can mess up the Error-insight feature, in most cases it will not make your application larger. Unless something like an initialization section exists in that unit you add, or a unit that it depends on contains an initialization section, then adding a unit to the uses clause will not increase your EXE size.  However the part about disabling RTTI is correct.

Comment: @Warren P with modern RTTI and default settings, the linker can no longer strip unused functions because it can't prove that they really are unused. See the comments below Eugene's answer.

Comment: @Warren P Your points concerning code and error insight may be correct, they were not asked by the OP. Regarding the correctness of my answer, it is correct in Delphi 2010 with default settings. Your point is valid for earlier versions of Delphi. I will edit the answer to make this clear.

Answer (score 5):

Referencing units which you don't use slows down compilation but doesn't affect compiled application size much (as the unused code is not linked in) *unless* the unit has initialization or finalization parts. If it has, the unit is linked.

Also I should note, that the more units you have, the slower intellisense works.

Comment: yep, I have noticed that. Sometimes Delphi IDE gives me some weird errors that really doesn't exist.

Comment: @Eugene I don't think your statement is quite correct with the advent of the new RTTI features and the default setting of {$WEAKLINKRTTI OFF}

Comment: @David I've made 4 different statements. Also, "new RTTI" has appeared about a year ago, and most users still use older versions of Delphi. This is proved by our download statistics.

Comment: @Eugene OK, I mean the statement that "Referencing units which you don't use doesn't affect compiled application size" and I did qualify that it only applied to the new RTTI. I was only trying to add value to your answer.

Comment: @David now I am even more confused. Historically the unused code was not linked (except some cases). You are saying that this is not so and *in general* the referenced units' code is linked to the application even if it's not used?

Comment: @Eugene Yes that's exactly what I am saying. Because the new RTTI can invoke methods dynamically at runtime, the linker can't remove anything. That is the state of affairs with {$WEAKLINKRTTI OFF} which is the default. I'm sure I'm generalising a little but that's the gist of it.

Comment: @Eugene Actually {$WEAKLINKRTTI OFF} is great when you are debugging because it means that you never get "Cannot evaluate because symbol was removed by linker" errors when inspecting things.

Comment: Or the unit itself recursively uses units which have initialization or finalization parts.

Comment: +1 for mentioning initialization/finalization. Any one know what happens in D2010+ if there is a class constructor or destructor on an otherwise unused class?

Comment: @Gerry: See http://blogs.embarcadero.com/abauer/2009/09/03/38898 where Allen Bauer explains that using class constructors instead of **initialization** makes it possible for the smartlinker to remove the class if it's not used.

Comment: @Thanks Mason - I've not had an opportunity to try anything after D2007 so far, but this was something that popped into my head when reading this question

Answer (score 2):

Each unique **uses** in your app makes your app larger, because it means there's more code in the finished product.

Don't worry about unused classes, though.  If the compiler can prove that it's not used anywhere in your code, it will remove it on its own.  It can even remove entire units if no code in them is touched.

Comment: and as I commented to @Eugene, with {$WEAKLINKRTTI OFF} the compiler usually can't prove anything!